# how to get json data in blackberry cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

1. contacts.json

   **{"GetCategoryResult":
   [
   {"CategoryID":"3","CategoryName":"News","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
   {"CategoryID":"4","CategoryName":"Daily Paper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
   {"CategoryID":"5","CategoryName":"Thanthi","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
   {"CategoryID":"1","CategoryName":"Newspaper","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"},
   {"CategoryID":"2","CategoryName":"Magazine","CountryID":"1","Result":"OK"}
   ]
   }**
2. main.qml

   **title: ListItemData.GetCategoryResult.CategoryName**

**please tell** how to implement this line in **qml** -------->  **title: ListItemData.????**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListItemData.GetCategoryResult[i]  will give u variant at i'th position in that json

for getting title as "Daily Paper"

use  ListItemData.GetCategoryResult[1].CategoryName